# Objective C: AVFoundation Changing Pitch is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

Can AVFoundation Framework change the Pitch of the sound recorded? If it's possible, how to change the voice's pitch?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK AVFoundation does not support DSP effects such as pitch shift (but someone please prove me wrong...). However, iOS supports [OpenAL](https://web.archive.org/web/20140604142344/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2199/_index.html), which gives you a lot more options. To change pitch, use

```
alSourcef(source, AL_PITCH, myPitch)
```

Comment: @Krumelur- is this the only code that i need to add? or there is something else?..

Comment: @GeraldStojakovic well, of course you need to change your playback code to use OpenAL

Comment: @Krumelur- only the playback code? not also the recording code? sorry for the hustle in asking this question sir..if you dont mind sir can you show me some example.. im new at objective C, thanks for consideration.